# Custom Styling of JqueryUI datepicker

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a datepicker on a webpage with other jQueryUI based elements. The datepicker needs to have a separate style to the other objects. My understanding was to use the themeroller  to create a style specific to the datepicker and with it use an appropriate selector, in my case it is ".dateTextBox".

Here is the element with said class:

```
<input type="input" class="dateTextBox">
```

Here is a snippet of the custom CSS:

```
.dateTextBox .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ff0000 }
```

The issue I have is that although my textbox has a ".dateTextBox" class added to it, the datepicker elements created by jquery only have their own jQueryUi classes; my custom selector is not added to it, and so the accompanying custom css that the themeroller exports is not being utilised as they refer to a selector that does not exist in the code.

I have tried adding code to the onclick of the textbox which will prepend any elements within the datepicker container with the dateTextBox class but this only results in some of the elements being styled by the custom css (see jsfiddle where the datepicker header is blue as set in my css, but the background is not red as set in my css using the " .ui-widget-content " class (jsfiddle seems to be applying its default jquerycss, anyone know how to disable this in jsfiddles?)

[Please see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktsk9j53/1/)

Is it as simple as an incorrect selector choice in the themeroller or am I on the right track with my manual addition of the selector class to the generated datepicker?

**EDIT:** -Appreciate everyone's help. I would like to clarify that the issue I'm having is using JQuery's themeroller to apply a custom theme to one of their own controls. I could manually make a whole css page from scratch specifically for my datepicker but I will possibly have this issue down the road with another JQuery control.

-Also worth noting is that jsfiddle supplies a default css for jquery, just because the calendar appears it does not mean that it is taking the styles I have supplied in the CSS window

**Edit 2:** - here is the themeroller website I am referring to, it seems as though people assume im just having trouble with css itself. click download theme and you will see the scope selector textbox which is supposed to allow for multiple jquery controls of differing styles in the one page

[themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.9.2&zThemeParams=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)

Comment: Do you want something like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/ktsk9j53/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/ktsk9j53/3/) ?

Comment: @antithesis that appears to be working the way I had hoped, what did you change??

Comment: Steal 5 minutes of your time to read about specificity and you will understand what I did. I just used the id of the container div which is "stronger" than using classes. (this is what @Salman A has already proposed)

Comment: @antithesis http://jsfiddle.net/ktsk9j53/6/ here is an updated example that uses the id class as a selector with the JqueryUI themeroller, and it does not seem to work. I'd like to clarify that Im not looking for a solution to change the color of the background of the datepicker, that is just an example. I am trying to properly utilise JqueryUI's themeroller which is supposed to allow one to specify a selector with which to set the styles of select controls without effecting the styles of other controls which might use a more base jquery css

Answer (score 1):

The way CSS selector work is by attributing points. The more specific you are the more point you have and the style apply is the one that has more points.

To apply the style you want you have 2 solutions. Be more specific in you css rule. Adding an ID will make you selector stronger. :

```
<input type="input" id="test" class="dateTextBox">
#test.dateTextBox .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ff0000 }
```

Note that the ID does not have to be directly in the control, it could be in a parent control.

The second solution is to use inline style. Added by jquery or manually.

```
<input type="input" class="dateTextBox" style="border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ff0000">
$(".dateTextBox").attr("style", "border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ff0000");
```

Hope this help.

**UPDATE :**

As i said, you could put all the datePicker into a container with a specific ID like so. The div can be replace with a form.

```
<div id="container" >
    <input type="input" id="test" class="dateTextBox">
    //any other control you like
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#container .dateTextBox .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #ff0000 }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65620/discussion-on-answer-by-mathieu-labrie-parent-custom-styling-of-jqueryui-datepic).